# L'Hôpital's rule for $\mathbb R ^n \to \mathbb R $ functions.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, partial-derivative

I want to know if there exists a generalization of  L'Hopital rule in $n$ dimensions? For example, let us consider this [problem](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101028114107AAtmZ9l).

There it is just said that we should take separate  path and see if they will end with same  number,but can't we generalize L'Hopital rule and partial derivatives in $n$ dimensions? Just a little hint will help me too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

l'Hopitals rule is, in its essence, an extension or corollary from the (extended) mean value theorem. There is no such simple mean value theorem in the vector case.

Your example

$$\frac{4x^2-y^2}{2x-y}=\frac{(2x-y)(2x+y)}{2x-y}$$

works because you can cancel the common factor. But take any example where $(1,2)$ is still the common zero but now without common factor, like

$$\frac{x+1-y}{5x-1-2y},$$

then on almost every line through $(1,2)$ you get a limit by l'Hopitals rule, but the limit is different for every direction.

Comment: but in case of different path gives different limit,it  means that limit does not exist right?

Comment: Exactly. If a limit exists, it is probably far easier to prove/compute using Taylor expansion than with some generalized version of l'Hopital. This is often also true in one dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts.

Let $f,g\colon \mathbb R ^2\to \mathbb R$ be $C^2$ functions over $\mathbb R ^2$ such that $f(0,0)=g(0,0)=0$. Suppose that $g$ is injective in a neighborood of $( 0,0 )$, so that $\frac{f(x,y )}{g(x,y)}$ is well defined.

Given a couple $(x,y)$ sufficiently near the origin, it is true that $$\dfrac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}=\dfrac{\partial _x f(\tau x,\tau y)x+\partial _y f(\tau x,\tau y)y}{\partial _x f(\tau x,\tau y)x+\partial _y f(\tau x,\tau y)y},\qquad \tau \in (0,1),$$
(this is Cauchy's theorem applied to the functions $f \circ \gamma$ and $g\circ \gamma$, $\gamma(t)=(tx,ty)$).

So, if $$\ell = \{\dfrac{\partial _x f(x,y) \cdot x + \partial _y f(x,y) \cdot y}{\partial _x g(x,y) \cdot x + \partial _y g(x,y) \cdot y}\}_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}$$

exists, then the limit of $\frac{f}{g}$ also exists and it is equal to $\ell$.

---

**EDIT**. After some thought, I'm not sure that the existence of this limit, implies what I was claiming. I think some extra hypotesis are required, but I can't see which are, right now. Actually I'm trying to prove it only using $C^2$ continuity.

---

**EDIT2**: Proof of the claim.

Suppose $\ell$ exists. By continuity of the function:$$h(x,y)=\dfrac{\partial _x f(x,y) \cdot x + \partial _y f(x,y) \cdot y}{\partial _x g(x,y) \cdot x + \partial _y g(x,y) \cdot y},$$
hence local uniform continuity, given $\varepsilon >0$ we can find $\delta>0$ such that $$|h(x',y')-h(x,y)|<\varepsilon$$
if $|(x,y)|<\delta$ and $|(x',y')|<\delta$.

So if we take $|(x,y)|<\delta$, nothing that $$h(\tau x,\tau y)=\dfrac{\partial _x f(\tau x,\tau y)x+\partial _y f(\tau x,\tau y)y}{\partial _x f(\tau x,\tau y)x+\partial _y f(\tau x,\tau y)y},$$
we have $$|h(\tau x,\tau y)-\ell|\leq |h(\tau x, \tau y)-h(x,y)|+|h( x , y) -\ell|<2\varepsilon$$
(if we take at most a smaller $\delta$).

---

The hypotesis on $g$ can be replaced with the much weaker: $g(x,y)\neq g(0,0)$ in a neighborood of $g$. However, I don't know how much the last one can be easy to prove. In the special case of radial functions $g(x^2+y^2)$, this can be reconducted to the crucial hypothesis for using D.H. rule: $\frac{\text{d}g}{\text d r}\neq 0$.

Comment: because  as i  know,to calculate limit  in 2 dimensional,squeeze theorem is used or they are trying to compute limits separately at separate path and see if they are equal,Hopital rule would be more easy

Comment: unfortunately i have reached limit of upvoting,so i can't upvote your answe

Comment: Please, look back at the answer, there's a mistake. Sorry for the inconvenience. It's explained.

Comment: which mistake sorry?

Comment: i will accept then previous answer,as i understand i it is impossible to generalize Hopital in high dimension

Comment: No problem. However, I added a proof, try to give a look. By the way, interesting question.

Comment: thanks very much  for your efford